# select query with leading zero

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query...but two nocompatible tables

```
SELECT
a.name
b.occupation
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.ID = B.ID
```

Problem is that the table1 and table2 has data

```
ID       ID
HV       HV
8        008
13       013
A5       A5
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mysqls [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function.

```
LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.ID = TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM B.ID)
```

Comment: +1, this is a better solution than mine, but it also spoils the index.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't see how you would keep the index, since you have to modify the column in one way or another to do a direct comparison :S Could this be achieved somehow?

Comment: Then I have to suggest you ensure your tables are in the same format. When you join, you are doing a comparison. This comparison cannot take place when the values aren't the same. You could also make a routine that casts numbers as integers (SIGNED og UNSIGNED datatypes), but that would still change the value, and thereby ruin any index you might have.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the values to their integer value by evaluating them in an integer context:

```
SELECT
a.name
b.occupation
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.ID = B.ID+0
```

But that's probably going to spoil any chance of using an index for the join.  To optimize, you'll have to store the values in a compatible format in both tables.

Comment: This won't work, entries like `'HV'` and `'A5'` will become `0`. See here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9a8f/1/0